# State is undefined when using CombineReducers

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm working on a React typescript project and trying to set up redux.

I have split my reducers in two at the moment and combining them using `combineReducers`.

Strangely when my application is run, `state` is undefined (I am logging `this.props` but nothing has a value.

I can see that the actions are being dispatched using redux-devtools, but it just doesn't work.

If I move my reducers the index file, all seems to work.

I can't get my head around it...

Please help!

I've literally tried everything! Been at this all day. As mentioned, not using combinedReducers makes this problem go away.

Reducer 1

```
const initState = []

const imageResults = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SEARCH_IMAGES' :
            return [...state, action.payload]
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default imageResults;
```

Reducer 2

```
const initState = {
    term: "initial term"
}

const client = (state = initState, action) => {
    console.log(action.payload)
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'UPDATE_TERM' :
        return {
            ...state,
            term: action.payload
        }
        default:
        return state;
    }
}

export default client;
```

combined reducer file

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';

import imageResults from './imageResults';
import client from './imageResults';

const reducer = combineReducers({
    imageResults: imageResults,
    client: client
})

export default reducer;
```

When the application loads, I expect 
{term: "initial term", searchImages: ƒ, updateTerm: ƒ}

instead, I get: {term: undefined, searchImages: ƒ, updateTerm: ƒ}

Also my state should look like this:

```
imageResults:{term: "initial term"}
client(pin): []
```

But instead it looks like this:
imageResults:[]
client:[]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you got wrong import?

```
import client from './client';
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Can't believe I've been going around in circles all day over something so silly!!!

Answer (score 0):

The matter is in this piece of code:

```
import imageResults from './imageResults';
import client from './imageResults';
```

I believe the path to the client should be different

```
import client from './client';
```

Try to pass the valid filename, please